# gwt does not load new image which has the same name

Tags: gwt, browser-cache

I have an image on my page and I am uploading a new image with same to the same location. When  I uploaded the new image browser still shows me old image. When i check it on the server side i see the new image. 
I don't want to change the name of the image because, it includes some database record ids etc.

How can I show my new image?
ps 1: i have tried ctrl + f5
ps 2: i have tried close and open browser
ps 3: i have tried to set url of the ime to empty string then ro url of the image.

Comment: Which headers are you sending that control the cache in the response? (`Expires`, `Cache-Control`, etc.)

Comment: I've noticed a similar issue, but it appears to be at the GWT level, not the browser cache level. In my case, if I upload a CSV file with modified data, but saved with the same name, GWT will ignore the uploaded (updated) file and use a cached one instead. If I rename the file, it will use the modified data. I suspect it tries to be sneaky with HTML 5 caching (which doesn't make sense; if the user uploads a file, you may as well use that, not a cached earlier version) but haven't had time to dig into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `empty the browser cache` (clear all cached data). You can have a look from a different browser, too (to check that *really* the browser cache is the guilty one)

If you use some browser-side development tool (e.g. Firebug), you can see what image is loaded from the server. Usually there is a 'clear cache' button for these purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned trying **CTRL + SHIFT + DEL** ( web dev's all time favourite ). User fire bug or chrome dev tools to find whether your new image is getting fetched by your browser.